# ConvertTo-Html formatting

Tags: powershell

I want to put an object in a table in a html file with the property names on the left and the values on the right.

But when doing :

```
Get-Process| Select-Object -First 5 | Select Name,Product,Id | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "test.html"
```

I get the property names on top and values on the bottom :

```
Name    Product         Id
armsvc  Adobe Acrobat   1528
chrome  Google Chrome   372
chrome  Google Chrome   1296
chrome  Google Chrome   1732
chrome  Google Chrome   2012
```

Is there any way to translate the table or I have to write each value in the table in the right order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convertto-HTML has an -as parameter that lets you specify either a table format or list format.  The default is Table.  Change that to List.

```
Get-Process| Select-Object -First 5 | Select Name,Product,Id | ConvertTo-Html -As List | Out-File "test.html"
```